# Encontrar valor de atributo com regex

Tags: regex

Recebo uma string por um feed RSS, cuja parte que interessa é a seguinte:

`&amp;lt;table feedtag="divinegoblin"` ...

Cada pedaço do feed sempre vai ter esse atributo `feedtag="..."`. Gostaria de pegar o valor desse atributo (no caso divinegoblin) com Regex. Não sei quase nada de Regex, estava tentando pegar usando `(feedtag)`, mas não sei como pegar o que está adiante (no caso o que está dentro das aspas). Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O jeito mais simples que você pode utilizar é assim:

```
feedtag="([^"]*)"
```

Desta forma ele pega tudo o que tem dentro das aspas depois de um `feedtag=`

Veja funcionando: https://regex101.com/r/BwibaW/2

Comment: Não é melhor colocar `"([^"]*)"` para evitar casar com uma aspas no meio do caminho?

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou exatamente do jeito que eu queria

Answer (score 1):

Seguem outras *alternativas* de encontrar o valor, no snippet abaixo tem um exemplo usando `.substring`(sei que na pergunta pede por **regex**) mas achei interessante colocar, e um exemplo utilizando **regex**, retornando *somente* o valor dentro das aspas através da [captura de grupo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

```js
var a = '&amp;lt;table feedtxag="wesas" feedtag="divinegoblin"';
var conteudo;
conteudo = a.substring(a.indexOf('feedtag="') + 'feedtag="'.length, a.indexOf('"', a.indexOf('feedtag="') + 'feedtag="'.length));
console.log("SUBSTRING: " + conteudo);

var regexResultado = a.match(/feedtag="\s*([^"]*)\s*"/)[1];
console.log("REGEX: " + regexResultado);
```